# How to write a script that does "Save for web" for mutiple resolutions in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

It's tedious to have to click to "Save for web" and change the resolution each time I want to create the image as a different resolution. Is there a way to write a script to automatically achieve this, for multiple resolutions as one?

Answer (score 4):

For that i myself use this function

```
function saveDocumentAsPng(d, width, height) {
    var fileName = d.fullName.toString();
    if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") >= 0) { fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));}
    fileName += "_wxh.png".replace("w", width).replace("h", height);

    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    exportOptions.horizontalScale = exportOptions.verticalScale = 100 * Math.max(width/d.width, height/d.height);
    var file = new File(fileName);

    app.activeDocument = d;
    d.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, exportOptions);
}
```

Note that it names a resulting png's with “_[width]x[height]” suffix.

I wrote my function based on a sample from adobe's javascript reference http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_reference_javascript_cs5.pdf (page 59).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but it inspired me to create a different version for my Android project that I'd like to share.
Just create a 144x144 pixels document and run this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// This is the scale factor that you can see in "Percent" textbox of
// the "Save for Web..." dialog box while changing the size of the image
var scale = [100, 66.67, 50, 33.33]

// This is the image size for the PNGs files names
var size = [144, 96, 72, 48]

for(var i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    var fileName = doc.fullName.toString();
    if (fileName.lastIndexOf(".") >= 0) {
        // Get the file name without the extension
        fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
    // Name each file with yours size to avoid overwrite
    fileName += "_wxh.png".replace("w", size[i]).replace("h", size[i]);

    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    exportOptions.horizontalScale = exportOptions.verticalScale = scale[i];
    exportOptions.artBoardClipping = true;

    var file = new File(fileName);
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, exportOptions);
}

Window.alert ("Successfully exported!", "Success");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that will export all files of the selected folder into PNG. You can specify resolution in this code and image quality will be good. In this code by default resolution is 600

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currentFile = files[i];
        app.open(currentFile);
        var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
        var pngFolder = Folder(currentFile.path + "/PNG");
        if (!pngFolder.exists)
            pngFolder.create();
        var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + ".png";
        var destinationFile = File(pngFolder + "/" + fileName);
        // Export Artboard where you can set resolution for an image. Set to 600 by default in code.
        var opts = new ImageCaptureOptions();
        opts.resolution = 600;
        opts.antiAliasing = true;
        opts.transparency = true;
        try {
            activeDocument.imageCapture(new File(destinationFile), activeDocument.geometricBounds, opts);
        } catch (e) {

        }

        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        currentFile = null;
    }
}
```

If you want to export in jpg format, just change extension of the file in the code in the following line

```
var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + ".png";
```

change to

```
  var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + ".jpg"; // For jpg
```

Also, you can change the name of the file and where the exported file will be stored according to your requirement.

Hope my answer will help you.